# tinyMCE webcomponent does not fire events with lit-html

Tags: tinymce, web-component, event-listener, lit-element, lit-html

I have implemented tinyMCE webcomponent with lit-HTML. Editor renders well, but events never fire.

```
import { LitElement, html, css } from 'lit-element';
import '@tinymce/tinymce-webcomponent';


render() {
    return html`
      <tinymce-editor
        api-key="n***************************8"
        @change=${()=>this.handleChangeEvent}
      ></tinymce-editor>
    `;
  }


handleChangeEvent(e){
    // this never fires
  }
```

Adding a listener to the editor once HTML has rendered also does not work.

```
firstUpdated() {
    this.editor = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('editor');
    this.editor.addEventListener("change", (e)=>this.handleEvent(e));  // this also never fires
  }
```

Any ideas about ways to resolve ?

Comment: [See the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event); ``change`` doesn't trigger on Key up; you want ``keyup`` for that

Comment: Thanks. That was just an example. No event is fired. Tried with `keyup` and no event was emited.

Comment: (I don't know Lit details) Lookup @change syntax; ``()=>this.handleChangeEvent`` is probably not right... in normal JS it executes a function and returns a **reference** to the ``handleChangeEvent`` Method..

Comment: No more luck :(

Comment: (Again, I don't know Lit details) Quick google search returns: https://www.kevinsimper.dk/posts/how-to-handle-litelement-input-onchange

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue with Lit, it's functionality missing from `<tinymce-editor>` as it doesn't fire the `change` event you're subscribing to.

It appears to have a really weird implementation of synthetic events - I don't think the component actually fires *any* composed events (though some browser ones might get through).

Instead of `<tinymce-editor>` firing an event called `change`, it appears to look for an attribute called `on-Change` (according to [the docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/webcomponent/#supportedbrowserevents), but the source [lowercases it](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-webcomponent/blob/ff6eab6b9ad84907209f0194c37b09f895379bae/src/main/ts/component/Editor.ts#L117)) that expects a string. It then looks up a function with that name using [@ephox/katamari `Resolve`](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/8ad4a1a2df1b79bc8856d99a0b7be69bcd238001/modules/katamari/src/main/ts/ephox/katamari/api/Resolve.ts#L13-L16).

Basically:

```
<tinymce-editor on-Change="handleChangeEvent"
```

Will look for `window.handleChangeEvent` and if it finds that name it executes. It has some handling for scope - I think you can pass a parent object and call a named instance method on it.

Lit *could* pass the actual function reference:

```
<tinymce-editor .on-Change=${e => handleChangeEvent(e)}
```

But I don't think this will work with `<tinymce-editor>` due to how the function is resolved. It only works with globally defined function names.

However, you can get [the source](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-webcomponent/blob/main/src/main/ts/component/Editor.ts) of their component and rip all this out for your own implementation. Mostly it just appears to be a lot of wrapper to hide loading their [JS from a CDN with an API key](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-webcomponent/blob/ff6eab6b9ad84907209f0194c37b09f895379bae/src/main/ts/component/Editor.ts#L241), but you can just load that too.

Then replace their [`on-*` weirdness](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-webcomponent/blob/ff6eab6b9ad84907209f0194c37b09f895379bae/src/main/ts/component/Editor.ts#L116-L132) with `this.dispatchEvent` and as long as you include `composed: true` it will fire the events you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am fine with adding the dispatchEvent method and I did look at the the component source code. However, I am not sure of what methods to delete. Could you please be more specific ? Thanks

Comment: @MadeInLagny I think in [`Editor.ts`](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-webcomponent/blob/main/src/main/ts/component/Editor.ts) you might just be able to replace the imported `Resolve` method with your own that dispatches events instead.